# Python - Read Multiple Files & Write To Multiple New Files

Tags: python, io, readfile, writefile

I know there's a lot of content about reading & writing out there, but I'm still not quite finding what I need specifically.

I have 5 files (i.e. in1.txt, in2.txt, in3.txt....), and I want to open/read, run the data through a function I have, and then output the new returned value to corresponding new files (i.e. out1.txt, out2.txt, out3.txt....)

I want to do this in one program run. I'm not sure how to write the loop to process all the numbered files in one run.

Comment: you want all files to be processed parallelly or one by one?

Comment: whatever is simplest. it just has to be in one run of the file/program

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want them to be processed serially, you can use a for loop as follows:

```
inpPrefix = "in"
outPrefix = "out"
for i in range(1, 6):
    inFile = inPrefix + str(i) + ".txt"
    with open(inFile, 'r') as f:
        fileLines = f.readlines()

    # process content of each file
    processedOutput = process(fileLines)

    #write to file
    outFile = outPrefix + str(i) + ".txt"
    with open(outFile, 'w') as f:
         f.write(processedOutput)
```

Note: This assumes that the input and output files are in the same directory as the script is in.

Comment: what is "lines()"? is it supposed to be readline()? readlines()?

Comment: yes, I had already updated the same to `readlines()`

Comment: oh okay, thanks, and the last part I'm confused about is "process(fileLines)", what's "process()"?

Comment: it is a placeholder method for the description `run the data through a function I have` that you added.

Comment: got it, thank you! last thing to fix (for others who find this in the future), second line up from bottom should be `with open(outFile, 'w')` vs `inFile` to do what I needed for this use case! thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking just for running one by one separately you can do:

```
import os

count = 0
directory = "dir/where/your/files/are/"
for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    if filename.endswith(".txt"):
        count += 1
        with open(directory + filename, "r") as read_file:
            return_of_your_function = do_something_with_data()
        with open(directory + count + filename, "w") as write_file:
            write_file.write(return_of_your_function)
```

Comment: what if it's same directory? how does this create the "out1.txt" files from 1-5?

Answer (score 0):

Here, you go! I would do something like this:
(Assuming all the input .txt files are in the same input folder)

```
input_path  = '/path/to/input/folder/'
output_path = '/path/to/output/folder/'

for count in range(1,6):
    input_file  = input_path  + 'in'  + str(count) + '.txt'
    output_file = output_path + 'out' + str(count) + '.txt'


    with open(input_file, 'r') as f:
        content = f.readlines() 
        output  = process_input(content)
    
    with open(output_file, 'w') as f:
        w.write(output)
```